# apache virtual host subdomains is accessable only by localhost

Tags: linux, apache, centos, xampp, virtualhost

i am try to make my `pic.localhost` virtual host accessible to public network(all of the internet)
now the problem is that it works only on the same machine in address `pic.localhost` but its not accessible even by `lan` network, only by the machine who runs it. what should i do?

i add and edited this files to make my pictures sub domain site:
1 - i included the `httpd-vhosts` file in my `httpd.conf` file.
2 - i added to `httpd-vhosts` file this lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName pic.localhost
#    ServerAlias www.pic.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/picture-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/picture-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

3 - i added this line to `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1                pic.localhost
```

4 - i restarted the xampp server

i am running `xampp 5.6.8` on `Centos 7` machine.

Answer (score 0):

**Centos 7** has a **firewall** that by default **blocks some ports** (including port 80). 
in the comand line, with sudo privileges try..

```
service firewalld stop
```

then in the terminal see you **CENTOS LAN IP** (ifconfig) and try to access that ip (ex 192.168.1.100).
 if you are able to access the web-server. then try from another machine and in the browser tipe http://centos-lan-ip  where centos-lan-ip is your centos machine IP.

Hope this works